# Make Laravel Accessor return query results

Tags: php, laravel

UPDATED:

I'm trying to add my own attribute with subquery results to the results of main query.

Now, I have Many-To-Many relation between three tables: Tournaments, Participants and Users.

Here is the defining of relation in Tournaments model:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'Participants', 'Id_tourn', 'Id_user')->withPivot('Rating');
}
```

The structure of tables is:

```
Users:
-Id
-Name

Participants:
-Id
-Id_user
-Id_tournament
-Final
-Final_place

Tournaments:
-Id
-Name
```

I need to have extra `Winners` attribute in my final query result where I'll have info of first three places.

Following the documentation, I've created an accessor and tried different variants:

1. That just freeze the system. Nothing happenes and in 30 second I get timeout error.

   `public function getWinnersAttribute() {
       return Tournaments::where("Id","=",$this->attributes['Id'])->where("Finals","=",1)->limit(3)->orderBy("Final_place","asc")->get();
   }`
2. This returns an error that "finals" column is not fount in Tournaments table, so `$this` doesn't have relation:

   `public function getWinnersAttribute()
   {
   return $this->where("Finals","=",1)->limit(3)->orderBy("final_place","asc")->get();
   }`
3. This returns blank white page without anything:

   `public function getWinnersAttribute()
   {
   return $this->with('users')->where("Finals","=",1)->limit(3)->orderBy("final_place","asc")->get();
   }`
4. This return "Winners" attribute empty:

   `public function getWinnersAttribute()
   {
   return $this->with("users")->where("Finals","=",1)->limit(3)->orderBy("final_place","asc");
   }`

I've created `$appends` variable to apply the accessor: `protected $appends = ['Winners'];`

However, I've checked the accessor, it works. If I return just:

```
public function getWinnersAttribute()
{
    return "123";
}
```

it works fine and I get `"123"` inside `"winners"` attribute of main query result.

The main query is:

```
Tournaments::with(['users'])->get();
```

The `Finals` column is in pivot table of Many-To-Many relation.

UPDATED:
When I try to return query to that Model without relation:

```
public function getWinnersAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->where("Finals",'=',2);
}
```

I get nothing in winners attribute as well. Like the subquery is not executed.

And if I add `get()` in the end of return:

```
return $this->where("Finals",'=',2)->get();
```

I get blank white page.
How can I solve that problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: is the getWinnersAttribute on the Tournament model?

Comment: @Casper, yes, it is

Comment: Are the winners actually tournament objects themselves or are they a different object that participates in the tournament?

Comment: Why not create a relation?

Comment: @Pablo, I forgot to mention that. I already have a relation, but I need special "where" clause in my "winners" attribute.

Comment: If `finals` is a related column you probably need to do `whereHas` instead of where

Comment: @apokryfos, just tried. Doesn't help, unfortunately:(

Comment: @Viktor Provide table structure and your current relations. If you already have a `participants` relation you create another relation base on that.

Comment: Pablo, Done. I don't know why, but I can't format my code as code(((

Answer (score 1):

If the `getWinnersAttribute` is on the Tournament model that means you already have a Tournament model you are calling by doing for example `Tournament::find(1)->winners` In your attribute you are trying too find the model again, and that could make it a forever loop trying to find a new one already having one etc. try using `$this` instead

```
public function getWinnersAttribute()
{
    return $this->where("finals","=",1)->limit(3)->orderBy("final_place","asc")->get();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I’ll check that version in 15 minutes and let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work because I need to use that with relation (inside relation). I forgot to said that.
I'll update the question.